# function as template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, dry

I am trying to avoid this repetitive code by writing a template function.

```
#include <algorithm>
class X {

public:
void get_amin(double *a){}
void set_amin(double a){}

void get_bmin(double *b){}
void set_bmin(double b){}

//...many pairs like above

};
int main(){
      X *x1 = new X;
      X *x2 = new X;

      //code that will be repeated
      {
          double x1_amin;
          x1->get_amin(&x1_amin);
          double x2_amin;
          x2->get_amin(&x2_amin);          
          x1->set_amin(std::min(x1_amin, x2_amin));
      }
      //repeatation
      {          
          double x1_bmin;
          x1->get_bmin(&x1_bmin);
          double x2_bmin;
          x2->get_bmin(&x2_bmin);          
          x1->set_bmin(std::min(x1_bmin, x2_bmin));
      }
      //
      delete x1;
      delete x2;
}
```

Now my attempts are below. It seems I am able to write the template but not able to use it. Other posts at stack overflow mostly focus on how to write the template. Also I could not find an example where a class member function is used.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
class X {

public:
void get_amin(double *a){}
void set_amin(double a){}

void get_bmin(double *b){}
void set_bmin(double b){}

//...many pairs like above

};

template <typename F11,typename F12, typename F2>
void templatisedFunction(F12 f11,F12 f12,F2 f2)
{
    double x1_amin;
    f11(&x1_amin);

    double x2_amin;
    f12(&x2_amin);       

    f2(std::min(x1_amin, x2_amin));
}

int main(){

    X *x1 = new X;
    X *x2 = new X;

    //templatisedFunction(x1->get_amin,x2->get_amin,x1->set_amin);
    //templatisedFunction(x1->get_amin(double*),x2->get_amin(double*),x1->set_amin(double));


    //templatisedFunction<x1->get_amin(double*),x2->get_amin(double*),x1->set_amin(double)>();
    //templatisedFunction<x1->get_amin,x2->get_amin,x1->set_amin>();

    std::function<void(X*)> memfun(&X::get_amin);//not sure here
    //templatisedFunction<x1->get_amin,x2->get_amin,x1->set_amin>();

    //
    delete x1;
    delete x2; 
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: A pointer to member function might be closer to what you want than templates.

Comment: @nwp Could you please provide example of the function pointer declaration and assignment in this case?

Comment: See the example for `Foo::print_sum()`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Answer (score 1):

`void (X::*getf)(double *)` and `void (X::*setf)(double)` are the function signatures for the two pointer to member function that you need.

Using C++11:

```
int main()
{
    X x1;
    X x2;

    auto lamb = [&](void (X::*getf)(double *), void (X::*setf)(double))
    {
        double x1_amin;
        (x1.*getf)(&x1_amin);
        double x2_amin;
        (x2.*getf)(&x2_amin);          
        (x1.*setf)(std::min(x1_amin, x2_amin));
    };

    lamb(&X::get_amin, &X::set_amin);
    lamb(&X::get_bmin, &X::set_bmin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers to member functions to reduce repetition:

```
void set_min(X &x1, X &x2, void (X::*get_min)(double *), void (X::*set_min)(double)) {
    double x1_amin;
    (x1.*get_min)(&x1_amin);
    double x2_amin;
    (x2.*get_min)(&x2_amin);
    (x1.*set_min)(std::min(x1_amin, x2_amin));
}
```

to be used like this:

```
set_min(*x1, *x2, &X::get_amin, &X::set_amin);
set_min(*x1, *x2, &X::get_bmin, &X::set_bmin);
```

If you have many pairs you could go even further and use a loop:

```
std::pair<void (X::*)(double *), void (X::*)(double)> get_set_pairs[] = {
    {&X::get_amin, &X::set_amin},
    {&X::get_bmin, &X::set_bmin},
};
for (auto &get_set_pair : get_set_pairs){
    set_min(*x1, *x2, get_set_pair.first, get_set_pair.second);
}
```